# How do you reset jasmine spy calls when using autoSpy with ng-mocks?

Tags: angular, jasmine, ng-mocks

I am using [ng-mocks](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/) for mocking and so far everything works OK with a few exceptions of some quirks.

I'm using [autoSpy](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/extra/auto-spy) to spy every method automatically so I don't have to manually spy on functions. So according to the documentation, I've got, in my `test.ts`:

```
ngMocks.autoSpy('jasmine');
```

And I can use the spy method to test. For example, I've got something like this:

```
// in the main beforeEach() while setting up TestBed
myService: MyService = MockService(MyService);

describe(`When button A is clicked`, () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    //button click code here
  });

  it(`Should call functionA one time`, () => {
    expect(myService.functionA).toHaveBeenCalled(); // This works ok
  });

});

// Further down in the same file
describe(`When button B is clicked`, () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    //button click code here
    
    ngMocks.reset(); // I don't think this does what I think it does
  });

  it(`Should NOT call functionA`, () => {
    expect(myService.functionA).not.toHaveBeenCalled(); // This DOES NOT work. 
  });

});
```

The second time around, I'm trying to test that the function is not called with a different button, but the spy counts the previous call and fails. If I run just this test with `jit`, then it passes. Or if I move this test case above the first one, the first then it works. I can't just do `mySpy.calls.reset()` because I haven't assigned a spy manually. I tried `myService.functionA.calls.reset()` but there's an error - `functoinA` doesn't have `calls` method as it's not recognised as a spy.

Furthermore, if I put a debugger just before my `expect.not.toHaveBeenCalled()` and check through chrome dev window, I can run this `myService.functionA.calls.reset()` on the console and then it works fine.

How do I reset the all spy calls in `ng-mocks` please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngMocks.autoSpy('jasmine');` simply calls `jasmine.createSpy` when a function / method should be mocked.

It means you don't need to reset it, because every test has its own objects and, therefore, its own new spies.

If your main `beforeEach` already contains `MockService`, nothing should be done extra. It creates a fresh mock for the service.

```js
// in the main beforeEach() while setting up TestBed
const myService = MockService(MyService);
```

You need simply to remove `ngMocks.reset();`:

```js
describe('root suite', () => {
  // in the main beforeEach() while setting up TestBed
  let myService: MyService

  beforeEach(() => myService = MockService(MyService));

  describe(`When button A is clicked`, () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      //button click code here
    });

    it(`Should call functionA one time`, () => {
      expect(myService.functionA).toHaveBeenCalled(); // This works ok
    });
  });

  // Further down in the same file
  describe(`When button B is clicked`, () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      //button click code here
    });

    it(`Should NOT call functionA`, () => {
      expect(myService.functionA).not.toHaveBeenCalled(); // This DOES NOT work. 
    });
  });
});
```

the code above ensures that each test has its own fresh instance of `MyService` with untouched spies.

Nevertheless, you can reset an existing spy as any other jasmine spy:

```js
(myService.functionA as jasmine.Spy).calls.reset();
```

Comment: For whatever reason the `beforeEach` isn't reseting my spies, but, I'll dig into it further. I'm sure I'm doing something not quite right. The last line works though! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used ng-mocks, but I went through their documentation and repository. Have you tried using `ngMock.autoSpy('reset')` ?

If you check here: https://github.com/help-me-mom/ng-mocks/blob/dc91dd9948caf8208f9afeb9058b87a4eef9eecb/libs/ng-mocks/src/lib/mock-helper/mock-helper.auto-spy.ts

Passing reset should remove the last mock, so if you do something like:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  ngMocks.autoSpy('jasmine');
});

.
.
.

afterEach(() => {
  ngMocks.autoSpy('reset');
});
```

It might solve your issue.

Comment: Hi - thanks! I've tried `ngMocks.autoSpy('reset')` but it doesn't really help - I've actually included that in my code above!  The calls don't get reset. I'm creating a stackblitz example so it's easier to visualise what's happening. will share when done.